# Capistrano deploy on more than one machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

I would like to deploy my rails application. I have one machine with nginx, two web servers and one which I use as a database server. Unfortunately when I reach deploy:migrate, it doesn't work because capistrano try to find the directory of the rails application "/home/user/apps/MyApp/releases/20141218160125" on my database server machine. I don't want to have a rails app there. I would like to use this machine only as database server.Should I upload my rails app there too, but not to use it in my nginx configuration? Is it possible to do it more clear - just as a database server and the code of the application to be on the machines which are used as application servers? Thanks!

Comment: You could exclude the database machine from capistrano deploy script, and connect to the db as a remote machine by configuring the database.yml appropriately. Good resources online for the specific database type (mysql / postgres / etc.) Examples: https://railsforum.com/topic/164-connecting-local-rails-app-to-remote-database/ & https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/134734

Answer (score 1):

Exclude your database server entirely from capistrano.  There's no need to deploy anything to it.

Your `config/database.yml` is configured to connect to the database already since your web servers have to talk to the database during normal operations.

All you need to do is assign the `db` capistrano role to one of the web servers.  Here's what my config looks like.  The database is on another server entirely.

```
server 'carnoustie.supremegolf.com', user: 'carl',    roles: %w{db web}
server 'standrews.supremegolf.com',  user: 'carl',    roles: %w{web}
```